# Using Collections.binarySearch() for predicate search (i.e., not complete match)

Tags: java, collections, binary-search, java-time

I have a list of timestamps sorted in ascending order:

```
List<Instant> timestamps = ...; // note: sorted in ascending order
```

Now, given an input timestamp `Instant inputTs`, I want to find an entry `t` in `timestamps` that satisfies `t.isBefore(inputTs) && inputTs.isBefore(t.plusMillis(SOME_CONSTANT))`, i.e., I am simply looking for a `t` such that `inputTs` lies within the bounds of some fixed-length duration starting at `t`. I acknowledge that there can theoretically be multiple such `t`s, so the search is allowed to arbitrarily choose between these.

The `Collections.binarySearch(...)` overloads expect a key, indicating that the common/intended usecase is to search for a "complete match"/identical entry (in lack of better words, sorry). However, in my case `inputTs` will be *different* from the entries present in `timestamps` as `inputTs` is expected to be a point in time shortly after some entry `t` in `timestamps`.

My idea is to simply make the `Comparator<Instant>` that I provide to `Collections.binarySearch(...)` return 0 when the predicate holds:

```
public class TimestampFinder {
    private static final long SOME_CONSTANT = 10_000;
    private List<Instant> timestamps = ... ; // initialize and sort

    public Instant find(Instant inputTs) {
        int index = Collections.binarySearch(timestamps, inputTs, (t, key) -> {
            if (t.isBefore(key) && key.isBefore(t.plusMillis(SOME_CONSTANT))) {
                // inputTs is part of the duration after t
                // return 0 to indicate that we've found a match
                return 0;
            }
            // inputTs not in interval
            // use Instant's implementation of Comparator to indicate to binarySearch if it should continue the search in the upper or lower half of the list
            return t.compareTo(key);
        });
        return index >= 0 ? timestamps.get(index) : null;
    }
}
```

Is this a proper (efficient) way to solve this problem, or is there a better alternative that I've overlooked? Note that the number of calls to `find(Instant)` will vastly outnumber the number of elements in `timestamps`, which is why I consider the overhead incurred by sorting `timestamps` to be warranted.

Comment: I don't see a problem. Binary search worst-case peformance will be O(log m) while your Comparator will be kind of constant O(1).

Comment: @gtgaxiola Cool, thanks for the review! Wasn't really sure if I was "abusing" binarySearch or not (if there was some other API that'd be more suited for this task).

Comment: Can this list have duplicates?  If not, a TreeSet will make this much easier.

Comment: @VGR No, `timestamps` will (should) not have duplicates. You'd implement it using `set.floor(inputTs)` and then do a subsequent check to see if `inputTs` is no more than `SOME_CONSTANT` milliseconds after the element returned by `floor`?

Comment: Pretty much, yes.

Comment: @VGR Thank you, this is indeed a good suggestion/better approach. However, I realized that I unfortunately cannot make use of a `TreeSet` as the `Comparator` that I am going to provide to the `TreeSet` (to have make it sort its contents by timestamp) will not be consistent with equals (as is required by `TreeSet`). This is because the timestamps are actually encapsulated in a more complex object (and the `List`/`Set` contains objects of this more complex type), but I left this out for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: You can still sort them fairly easily:  `new TreeSet<MoreComplexObject>(Comparator.comparing(MoreComplexObject::getTimestamp))`

Comment: @VGR yes, but that wouldn't be consistent with equals as equality of `MoreComplexObject` is defined in terms of other fields as well, not just the timestamp

Comment: You can map the objects by their timestamps:  `NavigableMap<Instant, MoreComplexObject> byTimestamp = new TreeMap<>(moreComplexObjects.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(MoreComplexObject::getTimestamp, c -> c)));`  Then you can pass your target Instant to [floorEntry](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html#floorEntry(K)) and [higherEntry](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html#higherEntry(K)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Collections.binarySearch` doesn't *have* to be used for exact matches. As specified in the documentation, if an exact match isn't found, it'll return `-1 - i` where `i` is the index of the next-higher element in the list.

Just do a search for `inputTs` with the natural ordering.  If it isn't found, then you can derive the index of the next-higher `Instant` from `inputTs` (just do `-1 - resultOfBinarySearch`).  If the `Instant` at that index is `before(inputTs.plusMillis(CONSTANT))`, then you're done, otherwise, no such `Instant` exists.

I *do* think your existing solution abuses `binarySearch` in concerning ways, for what it's worth.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your thoughts; +1. Could I ask you to elaborate a little more on why you think this use of `binarySearch` is concerning, please?

Comment: I'm curious as well.

Comment: It breaks the `Comparator` contract, mostly.  That's not a transitive `Comparator`.  Especially since this _can_ be solved with a perfectly valid, normal `Comparator`, that seems wrong.

Comment: Hmm, this is embarrassing, but I fail to see why it isn't transitive... As per the doc, transitivity is defined as "`((compare(x, y)>0) && (compare(y, z)>0))` implies `compare(x, z)>0`". With the `Comparator` defined above, `compare(val1,val2)` will only be greater than zero if `val1` and `val2` lie in different intervals. Therefore, for the lhs to hold in the first place, `x`, `y`, and `z` must all be in different intervals, and it then follows that `compare(x,z)` will also be greater than 0.

Comment: `compare(x, y)` can be `0` and `compare(y, z)` can be `0` but `compare(x, z)` can be nonzero, if e.g. `y = x + SOME_CONSTANT - 1` and `z = y + SOME_CONSTANT - 1`.

Comment: In perhaps more understandable terms, let's say `CONSTANT = 10, x = 0, y = 1, z = 11.1`. By your definition, `x < y && y < (x + CONSTANT)` and `y < z && z < (y + CONSTANT)`. However, `x < z && !(z < x + CONSTANT)`. This breaks transitivity and may have unintended side effects.

Comment: Alright, so I got too fixated on the fact that the line in the doc that stated the transitive relation only considered the > case and therefore thought that the counter-example given above did not apply (as `compare(x,y)` and `compare(y,z)` were not > 0 in the example given by @LouisWasserman). However, the violation is captured by the part of the doc that discusses how the `Comparator` must behave in relation to the signum function. Thank you all for helping me understand this; I feel silly now.