# Search array for a similar / most similar string Java

Tags: java, string, arraylist, binary-search, similarity

I am working on a project where I have book names in an XML file. These are then parsed and turned into an array list of `book` objects. Now I want to search through them. I have already successfully implemented `Collections.binarySearch()`. The problem now is that since the search looks for an exact match it will only turn a book up if spelled exactly correctly. For example if I was to input "Harry Pottr" I would not get anything as it is misspelled. What I need to know is a couple of things:

1. How would I go about making a system that can turn up results for a input that is close enough to something in the array. For example:

   `ArrayList<Book> library = new ArrayList<Book>();`
   To make this simple lets say I add some books to the array: `"Harry Potter", "The Lord of The Rings", "Wonder"`

   Now if I were to search the array for `"Wnder"` I would want the book to still turn up.
2. Is there a solution to this problem I can use with the `Collections.binarySearch()` function or do I need to make my own binary search to use it.

Finally I would like to say I am doing this in Java, so I can only use standard libraries and the actual language. Also I know there are similar questions out there but none really answer the question of how to apply this to a search.

P.S. I know about the Levenshtein distance. But if I figured that out could I work it into the already used Collections search function.

Comment: Read about the "Levenshtein distance."  Google uses this when searching, which is why `Harry Pottr` would turn up results for `Harry Potter`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yeah I have done some research into that. But can I apply the Levenshtein distance to Collections.binarySearch().

Comment: I recently asked a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51640370/using-collections-binarysearch-for-predicate-search-i-e-not-complete-match) that might be useful for you when it comes to generating ideas for how to go about implementing a `Comparator` that does not look for an exact match. Pay attention to the answer though: while my `Comparator` works for my use-case, it breaks the contract of `Comparator`, which in turn may result in unpredictable behavior in other use-cases.

Comment: @JanusVarmarken Thanks for linking the question. One of the answers you got is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

The standard library is only gonna take you so far.

If the list of strings (books title) is "small" then you could probably use https://github.com/xdrop/fuzzywuzzy (see `FuzzySearch.extractTop`).

Otherwise, if this is too slow then you need an index based algorithm like whats implemented in https://lucene.apache.org/core/.

Also, you can't apply binary search to fuzzy matching since there is no clear way to order the list of strings you are searching in for binary search to work.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas I will try to look into these.

Answer (score 0):

Levenshtein Distance is one of the best ways to find the similarity between two words, but that's not going to help you with a binary search, because binary search works on a sorted collection, and searches efficiently for an object that is equal to a given value.

With Levenshtein distance, you're not looking for something equal to your search term, you're looking for the item that is the most similar (smallest Levenshtein Distance).
You would have to evaluate every item in the list to find out which is closest.

Another possibility is Soundex. The Soundex algorithm tries to capture what the word sounds like. It throws away all of the vowels, and then encodes consonants, giving you a number that represents the word's sound. Using this, you could store a list of objects with their soundex values, and then search that for a soundex value close to that of your search term. However, you would still have the problem of not having an exact value to search for.

Comment: Interesting. So what you are saying essentially is that I shouldn't be using binarySearch if I want to also find similarity?

Comment: Yes, binary search is intended to find an exact match, and focuses on efficiency by not looking at every element.  Essentially a yes/no decision on each item that is considered. You are looking for the closest match, which, unless I'm missing something, doesn't lend itself to the binary search algorithm, because you can't sort the items, and you probably need to inspect every item.

Comment: BTW, here is an article that may help you: http://stevehanov.ca/blog/index.php?id=114 It describes using a Trie structure, and a bunch of other optimizations to search for the best Levenshtein match in a very large list of words very quickly. The sample code is in Python, but hopefully you can use the ideas presented.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Also thanks for the above explanation I now realize why binarySearch has the limitation you were talking about.